# QT version is not properly installed, please run make install

Tags: linux, qt

I installed QT-creator from a downloaded copy of `qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.6.1.bin` using

```
sudo ./qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.6.1.bin
```

in Ubuntu 11.04

I tried to add QT versions in QT-Creator/Build/QT-versions configuration and it asked for a qmake executable.

I installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-devel
```

which deployed qmake in `/usr/bin/qmake`

I selected it in QT-Creator/Build/QT-versions configuration as manual, `Qt-4.7.2 (System) /usr/bin/qmake-qt4` but `QT version is not properly installed, please run make install` message appears and I can't use it in QT-Creator/Build/Kits configuration.

How can I solve the problem and configure qmake for Qt-creator use in project creation?

Comment: this solved the issue of invalid QT version, but still getting back "No qmlviewer installed". It seems like a separate issue however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so this no longer shows up as unanswered:

To install all qt-devel libraries, use

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

Comment: You need to accept your own answer if you don't want this question to show up in the unanswered list.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package libqt4-core` \ 
`E: Unable to locate package libqt4-gui`

Answer (score 22):

This solved the problem for me on recent Ubuntu version:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Comment: This helped to me, however I had to restart Qt Creator to make this to work.

Comment: I had the same problem on `Debian Stretch`, and running `apt install qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-default` solved it completely.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 18.3 (32 bit) it also solved the problem:

```sh
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

So that Qt5 (5.5.1) was installed ready-to-use as a kit in QtCreator.

Although to install the Qt 5.9.0 version I had to explicitly download the package from  https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.0/single/ (2 Gb unpacked) .

Then I had to run this command in terminal:

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.0
```

Then this command:

```
./configure
```

Then this

```
make
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem even after `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` (it was already installed).

However the version of QMake I had pointed to was in the [Linux Processor SDK (02.00.02.11)](https://software-dl.ti.com/processor-sw/esd/PROCESSOR-SDK-LINUX-AM335X/02_00_02_11/index_FDS.html)

I fixed it by sourcing the environment setup before running qtcreator. The following shell script did it for me:

```
source /opt/ti/processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-02.00.02.11/linux-devkit/environment-setup
# substitute the location where the SDK is installed.

~/Qt5.9.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator -block
# substitute the location where QTCreator is installed
```