# Qt Creator 2.6.2 and Qt 4.8.4: Qt version is not properly installed

Tags: qt, windows-7, qt4, qt-creator

Windows 7: I have installed Qt 4.8.4 Win and Qt Creator 2.6.2 Win, VS2010 ([from here](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other)). When I try to open a project (previously compiled with Qt 4.8.3 / Creator 2.5.2), it says I need a kit (`no valid kit`) and eventually I end up at `Qt version is not properly installed`. All is shown in the screenshots below.

I have checked some solutions:

1. SO [QT version is not properly installed, please run make install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581528/qt-version-is-not-properly-installed-please-run-make-install) is for Linux
2. Some say, I need to install Qt SDK, [but where do I find this](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other) (this one contains [older Creator / Qt versions](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html)), and what sense would the individual installers make if I need SDK?
3. Some say, I need to add Qt to path, but what exactly? Creator? The Qt 4.8.4, the `qmake` dir?
4. Somehow I fail with this `make install`, nothing happens.
5. I have installed the 5.0.1 including Creator 2.6.2 as one installation, this works. But when I then download 4.8.4. and try to add it as QT Version, same issue: `Qt version is not properly installed`

Any idea what I would need to do or install.

-- Edit -- List of trials ---

1. Added my Qt 4.8.4 and its `qmake` dir to `PATH`
2. Re-installed Qt in different order: Qt 4.8.4 first / Creator 2.6.2 thereafter
3. Opened Qt CMD Prompt `qmake install` (as in the suggestions): `4.8.4\install:1: Parse Error ('INSTALLING Qt Source Package Version 4.8.4.') Error processing project file: install`
4. `qmake install` from Qt CMD. Runs 20 minutes, Laptop gets extremly hot, then it crashes

[image: Configure Kit]

[image: Kit]

[image: Qt version not installed]

```
P:\Qt\Libs\4.8.4>qmake\qmake.exe install
QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced.
Error processing project file: install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on SO: [How to install Qt on Windows after building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699311/how-to-install-qt-on-windows-after-building) I eventually got to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html

Simply running `configure` solved it for me, I did not build, nothing else. The installer did apply several patches, so I still do not get why I have to run configure.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Try to choose "qmake.exe" from the BIN folder, not the qmake folder, so in your case probably P:\Qt\Libs\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe