# QtCreator: No valid kits found

Tags: c++, qt, ide, qt-creator

Installed just the IDE on Windows 7.  I want to create a Plain C++ Project (Non-QT Project); however I get an error: **No valid kits found**.  When I click on Options->Kits, I see the *Desktop (default)* kit, and it shows no errors.

Am I getting the error because I didn't install a Qt library?  If so, is there any way I can bypass downloading/installing that and just use the IDE?

Comment: A "kit" is the compiler/linker you're going to use -- usually Visual C++ or Mingw on Windows. Setup instructions are here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-targets.html

Comment: @MrEricSir I'm using Visual C++, which was auto-detected.  The kit isn't showing any errors.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Found the issue.  Qt Creator wants you to use a compiler listed under one of their Qt libraries. Use the Maintenance Tool to install this.

To do so:

> Go to Tools -> Options.... Select Build & Run on left. Open Kits tab.
>   You should have Manual -> Desktop (default) line in list. Choose it.
>   Now select something like Qt 5.5.1 in PATH (qt5) in Qt version
>   combobox and click Apply button. From now you should be able to
>   create, build and run empty Qt project.

Comment: When I went to do this, I got a corrupted installation error :( Installing qt is no short task x.x Especially when you throw in source... Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Could you add more info about the Maintenance Tool please?

Comment: @mm_ Sorry, I haven't used QT Creator in over a year.  Maybe someone else can assist?

Comment: @mm_ Go to `Tools -> Options...`. Select `Build & Run` on left. Open `Kits` tab. You should have `Manual -> Desktop (default)` line in list. Choose it. Now select something like `Qt 5.5.1 in PATH (qt5)` in **Qt version** combobox and click Apply button. From now you should be able to create, build and run empty Qt project.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I got the feeling that I've seen much worse installation tasks. I wonder if that makes any ease but yeah that's how I feel anyway... hope you do alright

Comment: @SamProtsenko also make sure you select the right `Compiler:` before you clock `OK`, and also `Debugger:`. ho-ho-ho! + the `Desktop (default)` gets "red stop" or "yellow warning" icon sign prefix when it's not right and you can hover your mouse over them to see the message...

Comment: Thanks, @n611x007 -- I got this working eventually. Took some messing about in the settings.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck glad to hear that! for the record probably worth: https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW lists which version of "MinGW" is used in which version of QT, ie. helps to find the right version of the compiler for yourself. "MinGW" turns out to be ambigous thing to say...

Comment: So this solution doesnt work cause qmake.exe its missing from my pc... apparently it comes somewhere else; why qt installer allows one to install the creator without whatever dependencies it needs without warning, this is dumb as hell

Comment: If you can't see anything on the Qt version combobox, make sure you add your version of Qt on the Qt versions tab. I've been able to solve the problem applying @SamProtsenko 's solution and taking this extra step.

Comment: Where is PATH thing? Where to select version? I think the ui is changed a lot. I don't even see "empty qt project option".

Comment: Last time I had this problem I voted this answer up. This time I could not select any "qt version", there was just "none" available. So this time the following answer of @Joseph Tankoua solved the problem. First, I had to add qmake as described by Joseph, then I had to select it under "qt version"....

Answer (score 64):

Though OP is asking about Windows, this error also occurs on Ubuntu Linux and Google lists this result first when you search for the error"QtCreator: No valid kits found".

On Ubuntu this is solved by running:

For Qt5:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

For Qt4:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581528/qt-version-is-not-properly-installed-please-run-make-install) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694436/qt-version-is-not-properly-installed), though those entries are less SEO-friendly...

Comment: How do I know whether I need Qt4 or Qt5?

Comment: IIRC you can choose one or both.  Since they can be installed side-by-side without causing problems.  Your qmake files will say which version your project uses. So you may as well install both.

Comment: I used this answer to install qt and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513032/8013876) answer to select it.

Comment: On Ubuntu I'm getting:
`E: Unable to locate package libqt4-core
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-gui`

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski , try following the suggestions in https://askubuntu.com/a/801760/44630

Comment: this does not solve the OP question, this is an answer for ubuntu users

Answer (score 44):

**No valid Kits found**
The problem occurs because qt-creator don't know the versions of your qt,
your compiler or your debugger.
First off, let's solve the Qt versions. It may normally solve the others too ;).

You try to create a new project, run select a kit and then there is no kit available in the list.

Follow the steps:

1. Execute in your terminal the command: **sudo apt-get install qt5-default**
   to install qt version 5.
2. Verify the **version** of your Qt and the **location** of your **qmake file**. Do this by executing in your terminal the command **qmake --version**.
   You may have a result similar to this line.
   **QMake version 3.1
   Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**. What's important here is the location **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**.
3. Open your Qt-creator.
4. Go to "Tools>Options" or "Outils>Options"
5. Select the **Qt Versions** combobox and select and click "Add" or "Ajouter"
6. Then find the qmake file in the location of **step 2**. Here **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/** here you have the qmake file for qt5. Open it, click **Apply**.
7. Go to "Kits" combobox. Select Desktop(by default) or Desktop(par défaut). Then scroll down to the button to select Qt version: and list down to select the version you just add.
   8.Then apply all. Check your compiler and debugger and it's ok. You're done.

Yes I ...

Hope it's help ;)

Comment: this was a better guide to the qt-creator GUI than the accepted answer. To make it relevant for windows, install qt with pip (or anaconda) and run `find <path_to_python> -name qmake.exe` in git-bash to figure out the location of your qmake file. (For me it was `~/Anaconda3/Library/bin/qmake.exe`.)

Comment: I do not want to edit this (good) answer, but you need less steps: Find location of qmake: "which qmake". Then: "QtCreator -> Tools -> Options -> Kit (to the left) -> Qt Versions -> Manual -> File Dialog pops up -> Navigate to location of your qmake". That's it

Comment: On Fedora Linux the path is `/usr/lib64/qt<version>/bin/qmake` Had to manually add the qmake because the system wasn't auto detecting it.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was that my default kit's `Qt version` was `None`.

Go to `Tools -> Options... -> Build & Run -> Kits` tab, click on the kit you want to make as default and you'll see a list of fields beneath, one of which is `Qt version`. If it's `None`, change it to one of the versions available to you in the `Qt versions` tab which is just next to the `Kits` tab.

Answer (score 5):

For QT 5.* if you face error at Kits, like `No Valid Kits Found`, go to **Options->Build&Run->** (Kits tab) then you see a Manual category which should list Desktop as the default.

Just go to your OS Terminal and write `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`, go back to QT Creator and Start your New Project, and there you see the kit option Desktop included in the list.

Comment: how to do so in Windows 10

Comment: After installing qt5-default, on Qt Creator, start NEw Project, then when clicking on Options->Build&Run-> in desktop you have to select Qt version, then it will appear in the list

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package qt5-default` is what I get if I try to sudo apt-get install qt5-default. So I guess you guys here assume some preceding steps. Which ones?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problems after installing Qt in Windows.

This could be because only the Qt creator was installed and not any of the Qt libraries during initial installation. When installing from scratch use the online installer and select the following to install:

1. For starting, select at least one version of Qt libs (ex Qt 5.15.1) and the c++ compiler of choice (ex MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit).
2. Select Developer and Designer Tools. I kept the selected defaults.

Note: The choice of the Qt libs and Tools can also be changed post initial installation using MaintenanceTool.exe under Qt installation dir `C:\Qt`. See [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/84198/no-valid-kits-found/5).

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it goes well after I installed CMake in my system:)

```
sudo pacman -S cmake
```

for manjaro operating system.

Comment: Same for me... but chose to install via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for Ubuntu [2023]

1. Install **qmake6**: `sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`
2. Open Qt Creator.
3. Navigate to: `Edit -> Preferences... -> Kits -> Qt Version`
4. Click "Add" button.
5. qmake path: `/usr/bin/qmake6` and hit **"Apply" (otherwise it wouldn't be set)**
6. In **Kits** tab choose ***Desktop (default)***
7. Set **Qt Version** to the version you installed.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue (I did it on Ubuntu 16.04 but it might also work for windows and other Ubuntu versions):

While going through the installation steps, when you reach the step where you choose which packages to install via check boxes, instead of just pressing next with the default "Tools" checkbox selected also check the box for the version of QT you would like in addition to the "Tools" box. I usually check the first box which is the latest version of QT.

After doing this you should not see the "no valid kits found" issue described in this thread.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

#### on macOS: (as of 2021)

1. brew install qt<latest_version> `e.g. qt6`
2. `qmake --version` will output:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 6.0.3 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/6.0.3_2/lib

(This is the path to the QT installation --> `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/6.0.3_2/lib`)
```

3. Go to `Preferences -> Kits -> Qt Versions
4. Click Add then navigate to `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/6.0.3_2/bin`
5. Select `qmake` executable
6. Go to `Kits` tab
7. Select `Desktop (x86-darwin.....)` in the list
8. Scroll down to `Qt version` dropdown box and select your newly installed Qt version.
9. Click Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue on my Linux mint , first  :

1. install qmake : **sudo apt-get install qt5-default**
2. go to terminal and type qmake, you should get the path of qmake
3. create a new project (application widget type ), when you reach
   the kits part you should find desktop list item, click manage then
   go to the kits tab bar and  scroll down until you find a drop-down called
   Qt version, click manage and paste the path there then submit.
4. Now the settings are done !!