# Can't create console application project in QT creator - No valid kits found

Tags: c++, qt, console-application, qt-creator

I already add a kit in **Tool->Options->Kits->ADD**

and when im trying to create a console application it says **"No valid kits found"**

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found or provide more details about your system

Comment: as demonplus said provide details about your system, exactly what OS linux ? windows ? Mac Os X ? , second tell us how did you install qt creator

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. 
@demonplus I already read the link you gave me before i posted this question.

Comment: @niceman Im running windows 8.1, actually my qtcreator dont have auto-detected kits and QT version. i dont know why.

Comment: hmmm I faced a problem with qtcreator not detecting qt on linux machine, I solved it by adding qt manually in kits->qt_version then add, I browsed to where qmake is located and added it and worked, not sure where does windows put qmake though

Comment: and you can try adding the compiler too if it's not detected automatically, hope this solves your problem

Comment: @niceman i tried that, but cant find any exe files, I already install mingw with qtcreator using online installer, but i cant find the qtcreator.exe

Comment: @niceman i cant find the qmake.exe in the bin folder

Comment: well sorry but I'm not a windows user so don't know where are they :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtCreator did not find and tool chains.
Use the [Qt Online Installer for Windows](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) to install MinGW or MSVC tool chains.

Comment: Did you install MinGW separately or with QtCreator?

Comment: do you mean this? Qt Online Installer for Windows (16 MB)    (info)

Comment: I already have the MinGW before i installed QtCreator, so yea.

Comment: Uninstall MinGW and QtCreator. Then install MinGW WITH QtCreator using Qt Online Installer for Windows.

Comment: Im going to use MingW can i uncheck all components related to MSVC in online installer?

Comment: Qt 5.5.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 959 MB), how about i download this? instead of online installer?

Comment: I already install mingw with qtcreator using online installer, but i cant find the qtcreator.exe

Answer (score 1):

Click the Option hyperlink (or Tools --> Options) in the Kits tab, select the Desktop (default) entry below the Manual. You will see that the Qt version is blank, click the input control and select the right qt version and Apply or OK.

Comment: thanks for noticing that there is no physical answer here. that will help future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

If your qt sdk is x64 you need to install x64 mingw compiler. If not than install i686 mingw for compiler. [Here](https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/how-to-install-qt-4-8-mingw-and-qt-creator-on-windows-8-1/) is good guideline which you can learn how to install qt creator, qt sdk, and mingw for w8.1 machines.