# 'No Valid Kits Found' in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I am installing Qt 5.5 on a new machine, and I ran into this exact same issue last time I set up my environment, but I completely forgot how I fixed it and have been working on it for hours.  I've looked at questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found), and a few other places, but none of them solve the issue for me.

I am running on OS X, and the fact that I ran into this problem the last time I installed it makes me think this is a surprisingly common issue for just trying to start a new project.

Anyone solved this problem on Mac before?

Answer (score 4):

This happend for me because during the install on the versions page there is a tickbox stating (Use latest releases). As this seemed like a reasonable default I proceeded. This actually installed no Qt versions. So there were no kits installed. Hence this error during first use.

The problem is due to not making a selection in the list on the right, and can be remediend by running (Mac OS) ~/Qt/MaintenanceTool.app which will run through windows similar to the installation process. Select a Qt version on the page shown here.

[image: Qt Version Selection Screen]

Comment: I was just bit by this. Checking "Latest releases" is not sufficient to install Qt. You must additionally specify which latest release on the right.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I know - just summarizing

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator is only the IDE. You need the actual Qt **libraries** to build an application.

I suggest you uninstall your standalone Qt Creator, and install a Qt 5 package from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/. This package includes both the Qt libraries as well as the Qt Creator IDE.

Comment: I've installed the full Qt 5.5 SDK

Comment: In Qt Creator, go to Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits and hover your mouse cursor over the error symbol. It should explain what the exact issue is. (I'm guessing you need to install a compiler -- see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-requirements.html )

Comment: @JKSH There *is no* Tools -> **Options** on Qt 4.5 (based on qt 5.10.0) for macOS

Comment: @Alexis **Tools -> Options** on Windows is equivalent to **<AppName> -> Preferences** on macOS. This is common to almost all apps out there, not just Qt Creator: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8697/tools-options-does-not-exist-on-macos/ Unfortunately, I am no longer able to edit my 2+ year old comment.

Comment: @JKSH That makes all the sense in the world, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you may use C:\Qt\MaintenanceTool.exe to install missing components of your Qt Installation.