# No valid kits found in QT

Tags: qt

I am trying to create my first project using the QT.

Here is the problem I am getting into:
[image]
[image]

I am using Windows, so, the first solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found) does not apply to me.

What should I do to create a basic project in QT? It seems so painful to do that.

I think that the problem might is that I did not install QT itself, but just a QT creator. But when I try to install the latest version of QT from over [here](https://www.qt.io/download) its size is more than 7Gb and when I come 30% over the installation it just closes and deletes the folder in which I try to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Qt kit is detected by Qt Creator by its respective `qmake`. You Qt Creator simply can't find a `qmake`. If you have installed Qt properly all you need to do it is to add the location of `qmake` to the `PATH` variable.

The size of the download (7GB) of Qt seems rather odd. If your installation has failed (according to your post it does when the installer hits 30%), needless to say you cannot expect to have a functioning Qt hence Qt Creator will also not be useful in this situation.

Comment: Where should the `qmake` be?

Comment: Inside the `bin` directory wherever you have installed your Qt (I'm guessing in C:\Qt or something similar).

Comment: I do not have the `qmake` there even though I really should. Will try reinstalling the QT.

Comment: @ЯрикТроф I would recommend downloading the installation package again (or  at least verify the download with md5 if possible)