# I see "No Suitable Kits Found" error in qtcreator whenever I try to create a new project on Windows 10

Tags: user-interface, qt-creator

I want to create a C++ project with a graphical user interface. I thought to give qtcreator a try. I'm seeing this error saying " No suitable kits found" whenever I create a new project. How can I add these kits or avoid this error?

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Did you google the issue first? I see lots of potential solutions, but we have no idea what you've tried so far.

Comment: I tried googling and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found) so far. It's answered for qt on linux and their solutions don't work on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Just reinstall it. But this time don't go for custom installation in installation folder. Instead, choose the latest "Qt for desktop development"(like 6.3 or something). worked for me!!.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-inform you, I am using QT as GUI for C++ .

I had the same problem as your and to solve it I had to reinstall QT. This time I  selected the package:( Qt 6.1 for desktop development) unlike last time when I had left the default package selection to (custom installation).

[image: Qt package selection.]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in a rather roundabout way. Firstly, I noticed when trying to create a console application using Visual Studio 2019 that I was getting an error with the line #include . I then decided to run the Visual Studio 2019 installer again and noted that I had not activated 'Desktop Development with C++ Workload'. After activating it I reinstalled Qt5 and I now have a default kit defined and I am able to create Qt5 projects.