# QtCreator: No valid kits found - Linux - Qt6

Tags: qt, cmake, build, qt-creator, qt6

I have the latest version of QtCreator on Debian 11.6 x64 system. It has been working great but suddenly it won't allow me to open any of the examples any more. The error says "No suitable kits found" and proceeds to show a list of grayed out kits, some of which works great on an existing open project.

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: No suitable kits found]

And here is the kit I was hoping to use (which already works with another open project):

[image: Desktop Qt 6.4.2 GCC 64bit (default) kit]

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found) and basically tried all the answers there without any change. So I would like to explore in detail what exactly causes the error, going through the kit one step at the time:

| Item | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Name | The name of the kit. Should not really mattter |
| File system name | It was empty. Should it be something? |
| Device | Set to only logical choice for me: "Local PC" |
| Build device | Set to only logical choice for me: "Local PC" |
| Sysroot | This was set to empty even though the tooltip clearly states it should be set. It does not say WHAT it should be set to, and so I just set it to "/" |
| Compiler C | I tried all variations but I think it should be set to my local GCC |
| Compiler C++ | I tried all variations but I think it should be set to my local GCC |
| Environment | I left this as is. It says "No changes to apply." |
| Debugger | I left this as is. It says "System GDB". This should not matter I hope? |
| Qt version | This is grayed out and set to what I expect to be correct "Qt 6.4.2 GCC 64bit |
| Qt mkspec | I left this as is. It is currently empty. Tooltip states that this is only used by qmake. Given that all the exampels use CMake now this should not matter? |
| Additional Qbs Profile Settings | I left this as is. It currently is empty. I use Qbs in my own projects, but the example I am trying to open does not, so I naively expect this to not really matter? |
| CMake tool | I left this as is. It is an empty drop down box. |
| CMake generator | I left this as is. It is empty. |
| CMake configuration | I left this as is. It shows as a long list of -D macro defines. |

So I vaguely remember this window having small yellow triangles showing exactly why a kit was not suitable, however maybe there is a bug or my memory is just not it used to be?

Clearly QtCreator knows that all the kits are unsuitable but fails to say exactly why.

Any tips welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator 10 comes with a better error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just seconds after posting this question I found the solution. Somehow CMake was missing from my system! After I did a quick `sudo apt install cmake` and restarted QtCreator it now works!

I will provide some details in case this can help others, and I will submit a bug report/feature request to the QtCreator bugtracker to add a better UX in the unlikely case that CMake is missing (QtCreator should really be able to tell you why kits are unsuitable IMHO).

***EDIT:** The bug report is [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28895), please vote!.*

After installing **CMake** all my kits became suitable and now it looks like this:

[image: All kits available]

And my preferred kit looks like this:

[image: Kit works with CMake]

Please note the new values for

| Item | Details |
| --- | --- |
| CMAke Tool | "System CMake at /usr/bin/cmake" |
| CMake generator | Unix Makefiles |
| CMake Configuration | A long list of -D macro defines (unchanged) |

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! In my case, CMake was installed, but since I prefer qmake, I tried to create a project using it. It wasn't possible. But then I selected to CMake, and it worked. It's a pity: not even Qt uses qmake anymore.